# Graphite-API & Grafana: dashboard stuck: "Refresh every {{ctrl.dashboard.refresh}}"

Tags: grafana

My grafana dashboard seem to be stuck, I believe to have accidentally pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> for zoom.

I see the following instead of the normal time-picker:
Refresh every {{ctrl.dashboard.refresh}}

[image]

[image: grafana dashboard stuck]

- tried to export & import but result is the same problem
- can't find any issue with the graph itself (metrics etc)
- datsource seems to be working (tested ok, other dashboards show info ok)
- tried to understand difference between other json export and this particular json file but didn't find the troubling issue

Answer (score 3):

Spotted the error in the JSON file after all.

Looks like time block was wrong, it was:

```
"time": {
    "from": null,
    "to": null
},
```

and I changed that too:

```
"time": {
   "from": "now-3h",
   "to": "now"
},
```

sadly I could not find how to do that from the interface itself in browser.